# cypress: pass environment variables from command line with npm run cy:open

Tags: testing, environment-variables, cypress

In cypress.json there is one env variable:

```
  "env": {
    "AUTH_TOKEN": "token_1"
  },
```

I have multiple users in db and would like to test them separately without editing cypress.json. Cypress documentation provides two possible ways how to override env variables form command line:

```
cypress run --env AUTH_TOKEN="token_2"
```

and

```
AUTH_TOKEN="token_2" cypress run
```

When I run cypress interface with

```
npm run cy:open --env AUTH_TOKEN="token_2"
```

or

```
AUTH_TOKEN="token_2" npm run cy:open
```

token_1 does not get overriden with token_2. Why is cypress ignoring options provided in command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`npm run` requires a `--` to pass parameters to script `cy:open` in package.json,

```
npm run cy:open -- --env AUTH_TOKEN="token_2"
```

or use yarn

```
yarn cy:open --env AUTH_TOKEN="token_2"
```

or bypass the script

```
yarn cypress open --env AUTH_TOKEN="token_2"
```

or

```
npx cypress open --env AUTH_TOKEN="token_2"
```